# Infix for All (leaves)

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

`Infix[]` works only at first level:

```
Infix[(c a^b)^d]
(*
-> (a^b c) ~Power~ d
*)
```

As I want to (don't ask why) get the full expression switched to infix notation, I tried something like:

```
SetAttributes[toInfx, HoldAll];
toInfx[expr_] := Module[{prfx, infx},
  prfx = Level[expr, {0, Infinity}];
  infx = Infix /@ prfx /. {Infix[a_Symbol] -> a, Infix[a_?NumericQ] -> a};
  Fold[ReplaceAll[#1, #2] &, expr, Reverse@Thread[Rule[prfx, infx]]]
  ]
k = toInfx[(c a^b)^d]
(*
-> (c ~Times~ (a ~Power~ b)) ~Power~ d
*)
```

But this has two evident problems, because

1. `(c a^b)^d == a~Power~b~Times~c~Power~d`
   So what I get is not an efficient use of infix.
2. It is not robust, and fails for easy expressions such as `k = toInfx[a/b + ArcTan[a/b]]`

Is there an easy way to get `Infix[]` working for All (leaves)?

Comment: +1 for attempting to automate a joke

Comment: I can totally see this being _very_ useful :P

Comment: What's wrong with `(c ~Times~ (a ~Power~ b)) ~Power~ d`? You don't like the parenthesis? Could you provide an example of an expression where it fails?

Comment: @Sjoerd see edit. Also function slightly changed

Comment: @Sjoerd Yeah. I don't like the unneeded parentheization (sp)

Comment: @acl The story of the joke that just wouldn't die...

Comment: Since this question was not the joke I thought it was, I will add that I too am interested in an algorithm to find the minimally-parenthesized infix form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
ClearAll[toInfixAlt];
SetAttributes[toInfixAlt, HoldAll];
toInfixAlt[expr_] :=
 First@MapAll[Infix, HoldForm[expr]] //. 
   Infix[a : _?(Function[s, AtomQ[Unevaluated@s], HoldAll]) | _[_]| _[]] :> a
```

I used `HoldForm` since you may want the code to remain unevaluated. Here is an example:

```
In[781]:= toInfixAlt[(c a^b)^d/(1/2)]
Out[781]= ((c ~Times~ (a ~Power~ b)) ~Power~ d) ~Times~ (1/((1/2)))
```

*EDIT*

and,

```
In[792]:= toInfixAlt[a/b+ArcTan[a/b]]
Out[792]= (a ~Times~ (b ~Power~ (-1))) ~Plus~ ArcTan[a ~Times~ (b ~Power~ (-1))]
```

*End EDIT*

As to the superfluous parentheses, it is harder to remove them since often they are indeed needed due to precedence of various operators, but should be possible.

*EDIT 2*

To take care of precedence, here is an attempt:

```
ClearAll[toInfixAlt];
SetAttributes[toInfixAlt, HoldAll];
toInfixAlt[expr_] := 
  First@MapAll[Infix, HoldForm[expr]] //. 
     Infix[a : _?(Function[s, AtomQ[Unevaluated@s],HoldAll]) | _[_] | _[]] :> a //. 
     {
        Infix[f_[a__, Infix[r : (h_[___])],b___]] /; 
            Precedence[Unevaluated[f]] <= Precedence[Unevaluated[h]] :> Infix[f[a, r, b]],
        Infix[b___,f_[Infix[r : (h_[___])], a__]] /; 
            Precedence[Unevaluated[f]] <= Precedence[Unevaluated[h]] :> Infix[f[b, r, a]]
     };
```

Now, I get:

```
In[963]:= toInfixAlt[a/b+ArcTan[a/b]]
Out[963]= (a b ~Power~ (-1)) ~Plus~ ArcTan[a ~Times~ (1/b)]
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems that this also fails with `a/b + ArcTan[a/b]`. Am I right?

Comment: @belisarius I just edited to include that case (added `_[_]` to the pattern in code).

Comment: Somewhat in the Holding of the expression seems wrong. Try `toInfixAlt[Solve[x^5 + 2 x + 1 == 0, x]]`

Comment: @belisarius I had an evaluation leak in the code (shame on me:)). Fixed now (added `Unevaluated` inside `AtomQ`).

Comment: @belisarius See my edit, although not sure you will like the results :)

Comment: Thanks! I like it as much as you do :). I guess nothing will do that perfectly. BTW: Did you note the different outcomes for a/b ?

Comment: @belisarius Yes I did. The outcome is not really different, but *looks* differently, since `Infix` is now gone for that part. You can't have both - either `Infix` and more parens, or no `Infix` and then the usual form for the corresponding expression (operator).

Comment: I hoped for `b~Power~(-1)~Times~a~Plus~ArcTan[b~Power~(-1)~Times~a]`

Comment: @belisarius That's what I was saying. You can not do that with `Infix` without changing the formatting rules for `Infix`, since `Infix` puts parens around an expression inside it. Your desired outcome would correspond to `HoldForm[Infix[Plus[Infix[Times[Infix[Power[b, -1]], a]], 
   ArcTan[Infix[Times[Infix[Power[b, -1]], a]]]]]]`, but this results in the output we had before I added the precedence-related rules - that is, expression with extra parentheses.

Comment: @belisarius Won't help. It is a pure syntactic problem: look at `Infix[gg[Infix[ff[a, b]], c]]` for instance (produces `(a ~ff~ b) ~gg~ c`). I just don't see how can you produce something like `a~ff~b~gg~c` with `Infix` (may be I'm just dumb).

Comment: Get the graph from TreeForm[], sort (grafting) each level of each branch by precedence and then do `leftBranch ~ f ~ rightBranch` all over

Comment: @belisarius Sorry, you seem to not be getting what I am saying. It is not a problem of constructing a tree, it is a problem of `Infix` rendering (syntax rules). Please tell me how to construct `a~ff~b~gg~c` (without extra parens) using `Infix` (the expression is `gg[ff[a, b], c]`), then I may be able to do what you describe.

Comment: What I am after is the infix form, not the result of the Infix[] command. When I wrote my previous comment I was thinking about building a _String_ with the contents of TreeForm[]

Comment: @belisarius Oh, I got it now. Sorry, it was hard to understand from your comments - I thought you wanted to use `Infix` only. How would you then like to print / display the code - with `CellPrint`?

Comment: As all I want is a TextCell, I guess CellPrint[] is OK, yes.  And sorry about the confusion :(

Comment: @belisarius I was looking at this new formulation for quite a bit, and got a function that ought to do it, but it looks like there are parser bugs for infix notation. Consider this for example:  `a~Times~b~Power~(-1)`. Given that `Precedence /@ {Times, Power}` gives `{400., 590.}`, I would expect the result to be `a/b`, however it is `1/(a b)`, and many similar cases. This is a full stop. I give  up on this problem, and my suggestion is - don't use infix form *at all* (unless I am missing something).

Comment: As I understand it, in Infix notation the precedence is not accounted for. You need to arrange the tree so that, when executed left to right the result is the expected one. BTW I just discovered `BreadthFirstScan[]` that makes the tour around the syntax tree a piece of cake.

Comment: @belisarius I don't understand why breadth-first and not depth-first. To my mind, left-to-right execution corresponds to depth-first. But, if I am right, that is not very helpful. Consider `Times[Power[a, 2], Power[b, (-1)]]`. Depth-first scan will give `a~Power~2~Times~b~Power~(-1)` (right?). Executing the two gives different results however.

Comment: @belisarius Sorry, I must leave now, time to have some sleep :).

Comment: Leonid, your "parser bug" is actually a feature I quite value, which is that ~Infix~ precedence is all the same, so you can simply read the expression left to right, like I've been saying from day one of this whole shebang.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard I am about to leave, but since you value this feature, please tell me, what `a~Power~2~Times~b~Power~(-1)` corresponds to, if I read it from left to right as you suggest (I will only be able to read that tomorrow, I am off for today). In other words, why should I prefer the `(a~Power~2~Times~b)~Power~(-1)` interpretation to `(a~Power~2)~Times~(b~Power~(-1))` one?

Comment: @Mr. I wrote a comment saying the same thing .... and forgot to press "Add comment" :)

Comment: @belisarius seems you did, but I guess I couldn't pass up the chance to beat my old drum again. ;-p

Comment: @Mr. Ohhh Indeed, I did :) I see it now :)

Comment: @belisarius I must say, I never thought infix was this confusing!  My brain must be wired differently. lol

Comment: @Mr. And you thought this one was a mock question! :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's my approach, very similar to Leonid's:

```
(* In[118]:= *) foo[a:_[_,__]]:=Infix[a]
                foo[a_]:=a

(* In[120]:= *) MapAll[foo,(c a^b)^d]

(* Out[120]= *) (c ~Times~ (a ~Power~ b)) ~Power~ d

(* In[121]:= *) MapAll[foo,a/b+ArcTan[a/b]]

(* Out[121]= *) ArcTan[a ~Times~ (b ~Power~ (-1))] ~Plus~ (a ~Times~ (b ~Power~ (-1)))
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work correctly on `Solve[x^5 + 2 x + 1 == 0, x]`. Using `Unevaluated@Solve[...]` helps somewhat, but not entirely. Also, things like `#1^2 + #2^2 &` are problematic.

Comment: @belisarius Sorry, did not see your comment.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why I am helping you make fun of me, but...

```
(c a^b)^d //. h_[a_, b_] :> ix[a, h, b] /. ix :> (Infix[{##}, "~"] &)
```

Comment: I am NOT making fun of you. Your little amusement fired a lot of thought here. I feel more like having fun WITH you, and learning a bit.

Comment: Infix may work also on expressions with more than 2 terms, like `a+b+c` for instance. Your code does not cover that.

Comment: @belisarius okay :-)  Leonid, I really wasn't taking this question seriously.